# Where is the method document.getElementById defined?

Tags: javascript, html

*Note: This is only for learning purpose..*

```
console.log(this);
document.getElementById = function(){
    alert('testing');
}

document.getElementById('someID');
```

I have the above piece of javascript code written. When I load the page it shows an alert box saying 'Testing'.

So I am guessing `getElementById` is a method of the `document` object and I've overwritten it to `alert('testing')`, which is why its showing me the alert box when the page loads.

If that part is correct, shouldn't I see the `getElementById` when I expand the `document` object below? Am I looking for it in the wrong place or something?

[image]

Comment: I would strongly recommend against what you are doing. I see no reason why to do this and it will cause a lot of confusion, headaches and problems.

Comment: First of all what is the reason of using such code?

Comment: Depends on what you're looking at. If you just log `document`, you probably get the Document **interface**, i.e. the entire webpage, and not the document **object** and it's keys. -> https://jsfiddle.net/rhrgx838/

Comment: I guess OP is tinkering just for scientific purposes, and that's always a good way to learn (and break stuff in the way).

Comment: @nicooga I hope that is the case. Anyways, it's not our place to judge another man's code, although we *can* kindly advice against certain practices.

Comment: This was only for learning purpose. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method is in there. It's just Chrome decided not to show you.

[image]

Whether you should do this, however, is another question of its own.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is overriding the [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) function with your own implementation. The logger just doesn't show all the properties of the `document` element. Assigning it to a new object does the trick:

```js
document.getElementById = function() {
  console.log('test');
}

var doc = Object.assign({}, document);
console.log(doc);
console.log(doc.getElementById);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

#### An important note

I would strongly recommend you do not replace the `getElementById()` functionality with your own, as it can lead to all sorts of trouble. It would be far better to extend the `document` object with a custom function, instead.