# How does getElementById and other getElements works?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried `console.dir(document)` but could not find any `getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName` and other similar method in its property neither in proto how does it actually work? Where can I find such a method in the document?

Comment: Look at the prototype chain, `getElementById` etc... falls under `Document`

Comment: Instead of `console.log`, try `console.dir` and navigate through prototype chain. `document.__proto__` **->** `.__proto__(HTMLDocument)`

Comment: try reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478476/where-is-the-method-document-getelementbyid-defined
Its just your chrome not showing it to you. Try it in firefox and you can see all these things.

Comment: As the first comment already explained, just do `console.log(Document.prototype)`.

Comment: Got my answer in the comment box. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478476/where-is-the-method-document-getelementbyid-defined. (duplicate) Thank you.

Comment: Both chrome and firefox shows it to you, just go searching through prototype in firefox and proto in chrome.
prototype = proto

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the method document.getElementById defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478476/where-is-the-method-document-getelementbyid-defined)

Answer (score 1):

Many methods like `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName` are in prototypes.

```
document instanceof Document // true
```

You can find `getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName` in `Document.prototype`.

Also, `getElementsByClassName` is in `Element.prototype`.

```
document.createElement('div') instanceof Element // true
Element.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getElementsByClassName') // true
```

You can see more information here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

Answer (score -5):

`document.getElementById()` is only available as a method of the global document object, and not available as a method on all element objects in the DOM. It returns an element object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string ([see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)).